# ldd dependencies

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-libraries, ldd

I'm compiling 2 shared libraries ("A", "B") under Linux (Ubuntu 11)

The lib "B" is using exported function from lib "A" (linked statically with -lA)

But when I'm running ldd on "B" I just have*

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x004c0000) libc.so.6  
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00abf000)  
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00679000)
```

I cannot see my "A" dependency !?

Strange, I was (almost) pretty sure ldd used to display ALL static dependencies !?

Comment: firstly, static linkage integrates the code into the resulting binary. Secondly, the linker is allowed to optimize away unused definitions (i.e. you should take the address of at least one of external objects from the referenced library)

Comment: Ok found it... I misplaced the -lA in the makefile. Such a thing is amazing for a great soft like gcc !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link dynamically `libA.so` into `libB.so`, that is to build `libB.so` with something like

```
 gcc -shared -o libB.so B*.pic.o -lA
```

(assuming no `libA.a` exist, only a `libA.so`)

And then you could use `ldd libB.so` to check that it does link `libA.so`

Look for example into most GUI libraries like `/usr/lib/libQtGui.so.4` or  `/usr/lib/libgtk-3.so`, e.g.

```
% ldd /usr/lib/libgtk-3.so
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffe4cef000)
libgdk-3.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgdk-3.so.0 (0x00007f5a69c3b000)
libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f5a69a00000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f5a696c0000)
libXcomposite.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1 (0x00007f5a694be000)
libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f5a692bc000)
libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f5a690b5000)
libatk-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f5a68e92000)
libcairo-gobject.so.2 => /usr/lib/libcairo-gobject.so.2 (0x00007f5a68c8a000)
libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007f5a689c9000)
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f5a687aa000)
libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f5a68465000)
libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f5a68238000)
libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f5a67feb000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f5a67d4d000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f5a67b17000)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f5a678c6000)
libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f5a676c3000)
libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f5a674bd000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f5a672b5000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f5a66fbe000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f5a66d3b000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f5a66b1f000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5a6679b000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f5a66587000)
libXinerama.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 (0x00007f5a66385000)
libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f5a66176000)
libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007f5a65f6d000)
libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007f5a65d63000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f5a65b46000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f5a65942000)
libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007f5a656ba000)
libpng12.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007f5a65494000)
libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007f5a65291000)
libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007f5a65087000)
libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f5a64e7d000)
libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1 (0x00007f5a64c65000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f5a64a44000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f5a6482e000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f5a64604000)
libffi.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.5 (0x00007f5a643f7000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f5a6a50e000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f5a641ba000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f5a63fb7000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f5a63db1000)
```

Comment: Yes, that the point. My previous message wasn't accurate, I agree. "Statically" wasn't the right term (I'm a Windows user and I was talking about the .lib)

Comment: If I run the same makefile under an old Ubuntu (Linux 2.6.24-28-generic I do not have the problem) ! ldd works !?

Answer (score 3):

From `man ldd`

> ldd - print shared library dependencies

There is no run-time dependencies for static libraries, since they were linked statically,

Comment: Ok, but now if I set a runtime dependency on "A", I get the same result. On the other side, if I link them with an executable(gcc ok.c -I.. -Lrep -lA -lB -ldl -lz), ldd gives me all "A" and "B" as dependencies !

Comment: When you link executable with `-lA`, you must be using `libA.so`, and not `libA.a`. If you did the latter (as you apparently do for `libB.so`), the `ldd executable` wouldn't show dependency on `libA.so`  either.